# MySQL "unknown column" error message

Tags: mysql

I am doing a PHP tutorial that uses the code below to insert a new user into a database. In the video tutorial I am following, the code works, but when I tried it I got the following error message

```
Database query failed: Unknown column
'password' in 'field list'
```

Can someone explain what's wrong? Why is there only a problem with password? but it worked o.k. in the tutorial?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (1, 'kskoglund', 'secretpwd', 'Kevin', 'Skoglund')";
$result = $database->query($sql);


public function query($sql) {   $result
 = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    return $result;
}
```

[image: table]

[image: password field in database]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you should never ever build a web application with actual passwords stored in the database.  At the very least, you should do password hashing (see http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html), but even better would be salted hashes.  If you do this, and rename the column to "password_hash", your problem would also go away. :-)

Comment: are you sure you have a password column in your table? Maybe you named it something else?

Comment: @regality see the images in the OP. the password column is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used my crystal ball and can see that in phpMyAdmin, you have chosen your test database - therefore it works.

In PHP code however, you have chosen the server but not the correct database.  You are still using the default database.

Answer (score 2):

place password in backtick  like

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, `password`, first_name, last_name) ";
```

and also go to phpmyadmin and edit your password attribute, there may be space before password column

Comment: didn't work. same result. thanks for trying. any other ideas?

Comment: I've added images of my database. There's no space before password, if I understand your directions correctly.

Comment: @Michael r u using `md5` with password?? if yes then please increase the length of password field

Comment: rewrite the word 'password' in table attribute and try

Answer (score 2):

The word 'password' in MySQL is a reserved word. You need to ensure it is wrapped in ``.

Comment: You are correct Nishant - no need for ``. Although it is a reserved word.